# In 2022, how do I run a java applet on Windows?

Tags: firefox, browser, java

Browsers have disabled support for the API it uses. This leaves users with old systems that require Java; an embedded proprietary locked-down device that uses a Java web page to configure it, with no way forward.

It's difficult to find the original sources for the necessary programs (older versions of browsers, java, etc.). Surely someone must have compiled a backwards-compatible platform already?

The web points to portable versions of browsers with extended support. These programs install, but won't find each other automatically. It's unclear exactly what/which file I would need to import in Firefox 52 ESR to make it interface with the JRE.

The instructions on how to do so do not work. Trying to link the libnpjp2.dll directly results in 'unknown format' errors. How do I, step by step, get a browser that can run java applets?

So far I have found and tried these sources, without success;

https://askubuntu.com/questions/952674/unable-to-use-java-with-firefox-52-esr (Applies to Linux, not Windows).

https://wiki.rtzra.ru/software/firefox/firefox-portable (in Russian, instructions not complete).

https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable

https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/

Comment: Firefox 52 is too "recent" - you need Firefox 51 32-bit to make Java work ([link](https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Java-in-Firefox)).

Comment: I thought the ESR version also still worked?

Comment: You can find older versions online, e.g., https://firefox.softwaredownload.co.in/firefox-49 and https://www.filehorse.com/download-firefox-32/19467/ . **Caveat:** Since these are *not* directly from Mozilla, be sure to check them at VirusTotal.com!

Comment: Mozilla provides previous Firefox releases here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/